# Что за кодировка, как приобразовать?

Tags: mysql, кодировка

Отображается верно, но вот в поле бд записано так

```
&#1053;&#1072; &#1087;&#1088;&#1086;&#1089;&#1090;&#1086;&#1088;&#1072;&#1093; &#1088;&#1072;&#1079;&#1085;&#1099;&#1093; &#1084;&#1080;&#1088;&#1086;&#1074; &#1080;&#1079; &#1057;&#1082;&#1072;&#1085;&#1076;&#1080;&#1085;&#1072;&#1074;&#1089;&#1082;&#1086;&#1081;
```

Что это за кодировка рус раскладки, как записать в поле так чтобы была читаема? Если верно понимаю, необходимо преобразовать в utf-8

Comment: Это где... в бД лежит или где? с помощью какого языка надо преобразовать? и, в целом, зачем? .......... это обычный htmlentities.   а вот нужно ли это расшифровывать - не ясно. при выводе пользователю всё равно будет выведено как надо

Comment: Наверное вряд ли есть в mysql штука преобразующая сущности html в норм символы, но например в PHP  есть https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php    ..... так что как минимум можно смотреть подобные функции в том языке, с помощью которых записываются

Comment: Неверно.  [НапросторахразныхмировизСкандинавской](https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0400) это десятичные числа Unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это кодировка "html entity". Её можно отправлять на фронтэнд (если это сайт) как есть без изменений.

Через python декодировать

```
import html
html.unescape("&#1053;&#1072;....")
```

Есть простые функции для php и других языков.

На чистом SQL попробуйте [решение из этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176619/2101808)

Answer (score 1):

Это не "в поле бд записано так", а так отображает содержимое программа, с помощью которой вы просматриваете БД. Используйте другую программу или покопайтесь в настройках той, что используете, или в настройках ОС. Или запрограммируйте вывод сами там, где "Отображается верно".

Конечно, существует шанс, что в БД записана именно такая строка, а не "На просторах разных миров из Скандинавской" в кодировке UTF-8. В этом случае в программе просмотра БД, которую вы используете, создайте SQL-запрос, который будет преобразовывать эту строку в нормальный вид с помощью какой-нибудь функции (наверняка такие могут быть, или напишите такую самостоятельно).